# python: best way to find name inside another string

Tags: python, text, fuzzy-logic

I am dealing with some aggregated membership data from multiple sources. I have names in one column, and a long membership memos string in the other. I would like the best way to match the name into membership memo.

For example,

I would like the best way to find:

```
'Barack Obama'
```

in the following strings, since this data is aggregated and the formats may be different. here are a few examples:

```
"Member Data REWNEW:EX PAID ID:234242 Barack Obama WASHINGTON DC LAST CO 2834298:EEXE:00WIE"
"Member Data REWNEW:EX PAID ID:234242 Barack Hussein Obama WASHINGTON DC LAST CO 2834298:EEXE:00WIE"
"Member Data REWNEW:EX PAID ID:234242 Obama Barack WASHINGTON DC LAST CO 2834298:EEXE:00WIE"
"Member Data REWNEW:EX PAID ID:234242 Barack H Obama WASHINGTON DC LAST CO 2834298:EEXE:00WIE"
```

In the past, I've used fuzzywuzzy to do fuzzy logic matching. This tends to work well if I am comparing two strings, but not trying to find one string within another longer string. For example:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

print(fuzz.ratio("Barack Obama", "Barack Obama"))
print(fuzz.ratio("Michelle Obama", "Barack Obama"))
print(fuzz.ratio("Barack Obama", "Member Data REWNEW:EX PAID ID:234242 Barack Hussein Obama WASHINGTON DC LAST CO 2834298:EEXE:00WIE"))
print(fuzz.ratio("Michelle Obama", "Member Data REWNEW:EX PAID ID:234242 Barack Hussein Obama WASHINGTON DC LAST CO 2834298:EEXE:00WIE"))

100
54
22
16
```

It's very clear that the first two are very different (100 vs 54) however the second two do not appear to be all that different and thus this is not the best method.

Does anyone have any ideas on how best to implement this type of string search?

Thank you so much!

UPDATE1 :

I tried:

```
memo_string="Member Data REWNEW:EX PAID ID:234242 Barack Hussein Obama WASHINGTON DC LAST CO 2834298:EEXE:00WIE"
search_terms = "Barack Obama"

memo_words = memo_string.split(" ")
search_term_count = len(search_terms.split(" "))
memo_slices = []
for i in range(len(memo_words) - search_term_count):
    memo_slices.append(" ".join(memo_words[i:i+search_term_count]))
max_for_memo = 0
best_match_in_memo = None
for memo_slice in memo_slices:
    fuzz_score = fuzz.ratio(search_terms, memo_slice)
    if fuzz_score > max_for_memo:
        max_for_memo = fuzz_score
        best_match_in_memo = memo_slice

print(max_for_memo)

I also tried with search_terms = 'Michelle Obama'
```

The two scores were 52 and 50, respectively, which still presents the challenge that I stated in the beginning, which is that I would like some sort of logic that separates the two more definitively.

Thoughts?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way will just be to check for forename and surname. In your example, you could do:

```
search_terms = "Barack Obama"
matches = []
for memo_string in memos_list:
    for word in search_terms.split(" "):
        if word not in memo_string:
            break
    else:
        matches.append(memo_string) # triggers when the for loop doesn't break
```

And this would match all the memos which contain your exact search terms. This doesn't check that the terms are adjacent to each other and requires that they match exactly, though.

For fuzzier matching, you could compare your search terms against slices of the memo strings (some preamble left out for brevity).

```
memo_words = memo_string.split(" ")
search_term_count = len(search_terms.split(" "))
memo_slices = []
for i in range(memo_words - search_term_count):
    memo_slices.append(" ".join(memo_words[i:i+search_term_count]))
max_for_memo = 0
best_match_in_memo = None
for memo_slice in memo_slices:
    fuzz_score = fuzz.ratio(search_terms, memo_slice)
    if fuzz_score > max_for_memo:
        max_for_memo = fuzz_score
        best_match_in_memo = memo_slice
```

This should allow you to compare the fuzz scores of matches in longer text against shorter text. It gets a bit more complicated once you want to start matching the search terms against different sized slices in the target string, but you should probably look into regexes at that point (I just thought I'd offer some more possible solutions).

Comment: Thank you Rach Sarp. Super helpful. I added into the original post. Please see my comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use findall or search from the re module. Findall returns the list of matching strings. Search returns true if match is found. 
Ex:
import re
pattern='Barack Obama'
matches = re.findall(pattern, string)

Comment: Thank you I did this and didnt work: import re 
pattern='Barack Obama' 
matches = re.findall(pattern, "Member Data REWNEW:EX PAID ID:234242 Barack Hussein Obama WASHINGTON DC LAST CO 2834298:EEXE:00WIE")

Comment: The string that you pass in has Hussein in between so that's why no match was found. You can do a search on each word and check to see if you have both.
Ex:
if re.search('Barack, string) and re
search('Obama', string):
Do something

Comment: Your string has Hussein in between Barack and Obama so there&amp;amp;#39;s  no match. Try this:

if re.search('Barack', string) and re.search('Obama', string):

Do something